# Updating page from XML feed at certain intervals

Tags: php, xml, api

I really hate to ask these vague questions, but I could use some help figuring out the best method to go about this idea.

What I'm doing is fairly simple. I'm creating a page that will display data from several sportsbooks as accurately as possible. There are several different sites, all with their own APIs, but the data is the pretty much the same. Some of them have restrictions on the number of times they can be accessed per day so I'm trying to figure out how to go about that.

Because of the whole cross domain issue with JavaScript, I was looking into setting something up with PHP to retrieve the data locally. Would it be possible for a script to access each API say 4 times a day at certain times, parse the data locally and then serve it up with AJAX or something else?

Would it make sense to store the data in a MYSQL database and then query it? What I'm looking to do seems as simple as displaying live XML data, I just need to figure out a way not to exceed the API calls for the day. I'm fairly new to server side code in general so I apologize if this is blatantly obvious.

If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need indeed to store data locally. It can be either a database or files.

The set-up would go like that:

- Have a PHP script that would

  1. Fetch the data associated to an API
  2. Store that result in a cache file
- Have a CRON job that would run the above script 3 times a day
- Have a frontend php page that will display the content of the cache files.

If your server gets overloaded, you might consider caching the frontend php file to a static html file each time an API gets refreshed.

Comment: +1 for the cached frontend. It makes sense to make the results page static and update it when each API returns new data.

Comment: After digging into this more, I found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279316/beginner-data-caching-in-php) extremely helpful.

Just so I'm completely clear, these are the files that I'll need to create: 1. A PHP script that will pull API data and write it to a cache file. 2. The actual cache file. 3. The front end that will be the actual front end page. I still have to look into how exactly to go about executing the CRON job, but essentially it'll just run the PHP script. There's a way to make the script and the cache file private right?

Comment: EDIT: couldn't I just have it so that each page view of the front end page triggers a PHP script similar to [this one](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=13646) that checks the last time the cache file was updated? If it was over X amount of hours, trigger the script to make new calls and update the cache?

Comment: Yeah, this is the poor man's CRON replacement. The downside of that is when the cache has to get updated, if it takes a long time, the front page will look very slow or worse, will time out. When using CRON, your processing script pulling data can be anywhere (i.e. not visible from the web) because it gets executed as a command line PHP script.